# Consider the equation $b^n=a^b$, where $a,b,n\in \mathbb{N}^{\ast}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

DISCLAIMER: This is a self-made problem, and I don't know if there's a nice solution.

Hi, here's a conjecture I have for you; I'm not seeing the "simple" solution (at least for part (a)) at the moment, and I haven't solved any of the parts yet, but part (a) appears to be true for all the ones I tried, and I have *examples* of solutions to parts (b), (c).

---

Consider the equation (1) $b^n=a^b$, where $a,b,n\in \mathbb{N}^{\star}$ (positive integers).

Let $n=p_1^{e_1}p_2^{e_2}\cdots p_k^{e_k}$, where the $p_i$ are the distinct prime divisors of $n$.

From [here](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?f=58&t=577983), it is known that all solutions to equation (1) must have prime factors that are $\subset \{p_1,p_2,...,p_k\}$.

Thus, all the solutions to equation (1) are of the form:

$(a,b)=(p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\cdots p_k^{a_k}, p_1^{b_1} p_2^{b_2}\cdots p_k^{b_k})$

where $a_i,b_i$ are nonnegative integers for $i\in \{1,2,3,...,k\}$.

Let $\Pi(n)$ denote the product of all the nonzero $a_i$'s and $b_i$'s over [i]all[/i] such solutions for a fixed value of $n$. (Thanks chubakueno)

In all that follows, $n$, as before, is a positive integer.

(Conjecture) Prove that $n$ divides $\Pi(n)$ for all $n$ with more than 1 prime divisor.

(Problem 1) Find all $n$ such that $n=\Pi(n)$.

(Problem 2) Find all $n$ such that $n^2=\Pi(n)$.

---

(P/S: If you want a *small* table for the said $a_i,b_i$ values for some equations of the form $b^n=a^b$ that I already solved, please ask and I'll post them here to save you time.)

Have fun, thanks for your time!

Arkan

**EDIT (1):** Here's a mini table of the said values of $a_i$, $b_i$ to get you started (and $\Pi$ is defined as in the original post):

[*] Equation: $b^{10}=a^b$, where $(a,b)=(2^{a_1}5^{a_2}, 2^{b_1}5^{b_2})$.
Solutions:
$(a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2)=$
$(5,0,2,0);$
$(5,0,1,0);$
$(0,2,0,1);$
$(1,1,1,1);$
$(0,0,0,0).$
Product: $\Pi(10)=100$.

[*] Equation $b^{15}=a^b$, where $(a,b)=(3^{a_2} 5^{a_2}, 3^{b_1} 5^{b_2})$.
Solutions:
$(a_1, a_2, b_1, b_2)=$
$(5,0,1,0);$
$(0,3,0,1);$
$(1,1,1,1);$
$(0,0,0,0).$
Product: $\Pi(15)=15$.

[*] Equation $b^6=a^b$, where $(a,b)=(2^{a_1}3^{a_2}, 2^{b_1}3^{b_2})$.
Solutions:
$(a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2)=$
$(3,2,0,0);$
$(3,1,0,0);$
$(0,0,2,1);$
$(1,1,1,1);$
$(0,0,0,0).$
Product: $\Pi(6)=36$.

[*] Equation $b^4=a^b$, where $(a,b)=(2^{a_2}, 2^{b_1})$.
Solutions:
$(a_1,b_1)=$
$(1,4);$
$(2,2);$
$(2,1);$
$(0,0).$
Product: $\Pi(4)=32$.

[*] Equation $b^2=a^b$, where $(a,b)=(2^{a_1}, 2^{b_1})$.
Solutions:
$(a_1,b_1)=$
$(1,2);$
$(1,1);$
$(0,0).$
Product: $\Pi(2)=2$.

[*] Equation $b^{12}=a^b$, where $(a,b)=(2^{a_1}3^{a_2}, 2^{b_1}3^{b_2})$.
Solutions:
$(a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2)=$
$(6,0,2,0);$
$(6,0,1,0);$
$(0,4,0,1);$
$(2,2,1,1);$
$(2,1,2,1);$
$(3,0,4,0);$
$(0,0,0,0).$
Product: $\Pi(12)=55296$.

**EDIT (2):** Improved the notation.

**EDIT (3):** Narrowed down the conjecture (a) slightly.

Comment: Please, make titles more informative and less subjective.

Comment: There are infinitely many solutions, what do you mean by the product over all such solutions?